# Simplest way to test ASP.NET Webservice that returns JSON from some JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

We have a .asmx service that  returns JSON data. Can someone point me to a simple example that calls the service from a page w JavaScript ?
Tks

Answer (score 5):

You can use jQuery's get function.

```
var dataID = $('#WhatINeedForAParameter').val();
$.get('WebApiAddress/MethodName', { id: dataID }, 
   function(data) {
     alert(data);
     // Since your method returns a JSON object you can access
     // the properties of that object
     alert(data.id);
     alert(data.name);
});
```

Or if you want to use the long hand jQuery ajax you can do the following:

```
var dataID = $("#WhatINeedForAParameter").val();
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "WebApiAddress/MethodName",
  type: "POST",
  data: { id : dataID },
  dataType: "jsonp"
});

request.done(function(msg) {
  alert('You got this ' + msg);
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert( "Your request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

Comment: I think this won't work if the service expect parameters to be passed

Comment: I took out the gun faster then :P